# calculate the hour from the System.nanoTime() in java

Tags: java, gemfire

On gemfire, I am having one region ABC and within this region there is a column/field of type long.
In this field I am setting the value as `System.nanoTime()`.
I want to fetch all the record from this region which is of 24 hour older.
How can I do this?

Currently I am trying to make a query as below but its not working.

```
select  regionTimestamp from /ABCRegion where (((((regionTimestamp-currentTimeStamp)/ 1000000000))/3600)>24)
```

Any help suggestion must be appreciated.

Comment: Besides the answers, `currentTimeStamp` will always be later than `regionTimestamp` since that's recorded in the past .Therefore it should be `currentTimeStamp-regionTimestamp` to calculate the delta time instead of the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: System.nanoTime() is reset whenever your computer restarts so it's not a good choice to store in a database. This also means the time is local to each machine.

`LocalDateTime.now()` is a nano second resolution wall clock which doesn't reset on a reboot and is more likely to work across machines.

---

Never the less, you could rearrange this and calculate

```
long now = ...
long aDayAgo = now - 86_400_000_000_000L; // 24 hours.

search for ... where regionTimestamp > aDayAgo
```

Comment: Would it not be better to use `TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toHours(now - regionTimestamp) > 24` or `TimeUnit.HOURS.toNanos(24)` instead of  `86_400_000_000_000L` since it's more readable/maintainable? Or is there an advantage to your approach, just curious

Comment: My concern is that how i would made a query for the gemfire and there is some limitations so i cant change that to LocaldateTime